# List updating unexpectedly

Tags: java, list

I have a list that is unexpectedly updating.  I have a function that returns a list.  I want to call it twice with different parameters and store the results in a single long list.

```
List<URL> resultUrls = new ArrayList<URL>();
webPages.runSearch(parameter1);                   // runs search and stores result in a public variable of the object webPages
resultUrls = webPages.getUrls();                  // returns public variable
webPages.runSearch(parameter2);
resultUrls.addAll(webPages.getUrls());
```

Prior to executing the last line, resultUrls already contains the updated results from runSearch using parameter2.  I want it to still hold the results from runSearch with parameter1.  The net result is that I get two copies of the search using parameter2 appended to each other.  What I want is the search using parameter1 appended with the search from parameter2 stored in the resultUrls variable.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<URL> resultUrls = new ArrayList<URL>();
webPages.runSearch(parameter1);                   // runs search and stores result in a public variable of the object webPages
resultUrls = webPages.getUrls();                  // returns public variable
```

After this point you have *discarded* the `ArrayList` you created in the first statement, and now `resultUrls` is a reference to the public variable that is a member of the object referenced by `webPages`.

You should be able to figure it out from this point.

Hint: the last statement above should be

```
resultUrls.addAll(webPages.getUrls());
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't know what `webPages` is, but I suspect the problem is that your `runSearch` method doesn't create a new list - it just mutates the existing one. I suspect you want to create a *copy* of the first list. Note that you don't need the original `ArrayList<URL>` you were creating, as you were discarding it anyway.

```
webPages.runSearch(parameter1); 
List<URL> resultUrls = new ArrayList<URL>(webPages.getUrls());
webPages.runSearch(parameter2);
resultUrls.addAll(webPages.getUrls());
```

(You *could* start with an empty list and just add the results of `webPages.getUrls()` after the first call, but it seems a little pointless.)

I suggest you actually change your design, however, so that the type of `webPages` isn't stateful anyway - instead, make `runSearch` return the relevant list. At that point, you can have:

```
List<URL> resultUrls = webPages.runSearch(parameter1);
resultUrls.addAll(webPages.runSearch(parameter2));
```